# How to serve multiple interfaces in Capnproto

Tags: capnproto

In the [calculator example](https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto/tree/master/c%2B%2B/samples), I have added a new interface in the capnp file like below:

```
interface Main {
  getCalculator @0 () -> (calculator :Calculator);
}
```

My objective is to make use of multiple interfaces through one implementation `Main`. How can I achieve this? The extra client code is below (when I try to use `calculator` it throws a null capability exception):

```cpp
capnp::EzRpcClient client1(argv[1]);
Main::Client main = client1.getMain<Main>();
auto& waitScope1 = client1.getWaitScope();

auto request1 = main.getCalculatorRequest();
auto evalPromise1 = request1.send();
auto response1 = evalPromise1.wait(waitScope1);
auto calculator = response1.getCalculator();
auto request = calculator.evaluateRequest();
request.getExpression().setLiteral(123);

// Send it, which returns a promise for the result (without blocking).
auto evalPromise = request.send();

// Using the promise, create a pipelined request to call read() on the
// returned object, and then send that.
auto readPromise = evalPromise.getValue().readRequest().send();

// Now that we've sent all the requests, wait for the response.  Until this
// point, we haven't waited at all!
auto response = readPromise.wait(waitScope1);
KJ_ASSERT(response.getValue() == 123);
```

Changes to the server's main implementation file are given below:

```cpp
class MainImpl : public Main::Server {
  public:
    kj::Promise<void> getCalculator(GetCalculatorContext context) override {
      context.getResults();
      return kj::READY_NOW;
    }
};
```

The main function in server serves `MainImpl`. I do get the calculator object but how can I further invoke methods on that object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getCalculator()` function on the server side does not do anything right now. You need to actually set the result if you want the `Calculator` to get back to the client. That's why you get your "null capability exception".

Something like this:

```cpp
class MainImpl : public Main::Server {
  public:
    kj::Promise<void> getCalculator(GetCalculatorContext context) override {
      context.getResults().setCalculator(<the calculator capability>);
      return kj::READY_NOW;
    }
};
```

That will require you to create the `Calculator` client on the server side (i.e. you won't do `Calculator::Client calculator = client.getMain<Calculator>();` on the client side anymore, since `calculator` will come from `getCalculator()`).

Comment: I tried doing `context.getResults().setCalculator(kj::heap<CalculatorImpl>(CalculatorImpl()));` but still having same problem.

Comment: Which version of Cap'n Proto are you using?

Comment: 0.7.0 which is stock version with ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Nevermind I forgot to restart server after code change. It is working. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.